# Why nested class call like this "val statusData:StatusData?=StatusData()"?

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, jpa

Why nested class call in this way val statusData:StatusData?=StatusData().

```
class NestedModel{
    var id: String? = null
    val statusData:StatusData?=StatusData() // Like this
    class StatusData {
        var internal_status: String? = null
        var ot_code: String? = null
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question here? Are you asking how does this code work?

Comment: yes Bro.The nested  class call''s like this  val statusData:StatusData?=StatusData().

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not understandable. But i thing your question is this. Why we can not call StatusData() from nestedModel object. For this we use "inner class" key word.

Example:

```
fun main() {
val nestedModel = NestedModel()
val statusData = nestedModel.StatusData()
}

class NestedModel {
var id: String? = null

inner class StatusData {
    var internal_status: String? = null
    var ot_code: String? = null
  }
}
```